# How to :Autorun scriptshell after user log-in

Tags: shell-script, users, login, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am writing a program in java programming language on Raspberry pi. As you know Raspberry pi is working on Rasbian Unix based OS.

I have created my java fx gui application and set it to myscript shell. So, if I run this my script shell as "`./myscriptshell.sh`" it is able to open GUI application on my LCD screen.

So, what I want is to run this script after created user is logged-in.

like:

```
userlogin : bla
password : blabla
```

then my shell script should run automatically.

I have read all articles related to.

> .bashrc
>
> rc.profile
>
> crontab -e

But unfortunately I couldn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try adding at the end of `.profile`

```
./myscriptshell.sh > myscriptshell.log 2>&1
```

this sould start `myscriptshell`, logging any error to `myscriptshell.log`

as cas pointed out, you'd better add `&` at the end of line.

Comment: It didn't change anything.I added "./myscriptshell.sh > myscriptshell.log 2>&1" command to my "/etc/profile" but it didnt run anything

Comment: It worked but like this.Adding "sudo sh /myscriptshell.sh > myscriptshell.log 2>&1"    .But It also enables and run this java file for "root" user.I just would like to do it for "bla" user, not for root user.Also this"bla" user is adjusted as a root privilige user.Could you please help me how can ı do that ?

Comment: probably should run it in the background when being run from `~/.profile`.  script should probably also check to see if it's already running and exit if it is.

Comment: I am able to quit by **ctrl + x** but ı dont want to apply it to root user.Because ı am going to connect to the system by root user with ssh connection type.